# rasterToPoints in R does not return integer values

Tags: raster, points

I am trying to convert a raster into a spatial point data frame using:

```
mypts <- rasterToPoints(myraster, spatial=T)
```

The input raster 'myraster' takes only integer values: 1,2, 3, 4, 5. But then the output `mypts@data` has non-integer values such as 4.638932.

My temporary solution is to do a simple rounding up:

```
mydata <- round(mypts@data) # deal with floating points - temporary solution
```

I did some search suggesting the issue is that the converted spatial points are not positioned at the center of the pixel. I guess this has something to do with the extent. Does anyone have a suggested solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption is wrong. If you get values like `4.638932` then the values of the raster are not integer.  See these examples.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
x <- rasterToPoints(r, spatial=T) 
head(x, 3)
#  layer
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
```

Non-integer data

```
rr <- sqrt(r)
xx <- rasterToPoints(rr, spatial=T) 
head(xx, 3)
#     layer
#1 1.000000
#2 1.414214
#3 1.732051
```

To check with your data, you could do the equivalent of this (round the raster values)

```
rrr <- round(rr)
xxx <- rasterToPoints(rrr, spatial=T) 
head(xxx, 3)
#  layer
#1     1
#2     1
#3     2
```

It has nothing to do with the centers of the cells or the extent.

Comment: Thanks. My raw data `myraster` is a large remote-sensing data. Here is its frequency table:  `freq(myraster)
     value    count
[1,]     1     7133
[2,]     2     9122
[3,]     3   421431
[4,]     4    78008
[5,]     5   190547
[6,]    NA 18210615`

Comment: Feel free to edit your question. Note that `freq` rounds to integers, unless you change the `digits` argument